# Creating a Non-Int and Non-Guid Unique Identifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a way SQL Server can generate a unique identifier that is not an increment Int or a GUID.

The Unique ID can be a combination of letters and numbers and has no other characters, and as previously mentioned Must be Unique.

ie `AS93K239DFAK`

And if possible must always start with `AS` or end with an `K`

It would be nice if this unique id can be generated automatically when there is an `Insert` like GUIDs and IsIdentity = Yes does.  It can be a random number, it is not predetermined in the app.

Is doing something like this possible, or does it have to be generated application-side?

Comment: Is guess-ability an issue? i.e is an encoded incrementing integer acceptable?

Comment: I'm looking for a way SQL Server can generate a unique identifier that is not an increment Int or a GUID.

Comment: In general this is a **terrible idea**.  The built-in unique ids are always better to use - there are very thorny issues around handling contention that SQL Server handles for you with those, and it's extremely difficult to roll your own solution that works well.

Comment: Aye but does it matter of the sequence of non-int unique values is derivable? i.e. 'AS' + <base32 encoded high seed identity> + 'K'

Comment: Ok so either there has to be some encoding like Alex asked or it would have to be on the app side, what would you suggest?

Comment: I'm going to jump into the same boat as @JNK.  Perhaps you could explain your reason for wanting to do this?  It feels like you're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: What's the use case/reasoning here?

Comment: @Alexk, can you share your solution, at least it can be somewhat helpful considering i don't know even know how to do what you're saying.

Comment: @JNK: lets say its for a custom Invoice # system or something.

Comment: @ZeeTee then you should use the integrated techniques and just add a prefix/suffix as alex suggests

Comment: @JNK, sounds great, how do you do it?

Comment: Also I'm not sure why this is getting downvotes.  It's a common issue.

Comment: on insert you take the identity value and add "AS" to the front and "K" to the rear. Otherwise you're stabbing yourself in the eye. With a gopher.

Comment: I think you are wasting valuable time re-inventing GUIDs when you could be inventing the next wheel. </sarcasm> @Zee Tee - Just use a GUID and move on with life. This is a solved problem and your home-baked solution will undoubtedly be inferior.

Answer (score 5):

From comments, it sounds like you would be OK with using an `IDENTITY` field and padding it with 0s and adding a prefix/suffix.  Something like this should work:

**1** - Add an `IDENTITY` field which will be auto-incremented
**2** - Add a calculated field in the table with the definition of:

`[InvoiceNo] AS ('AS' + RIGHT(('000000000' + CAST(idfield AS varchar(9))), 9) + 'FAK')`

This will give you `invoiceno` in the format of:

```
AS000000001FAK
AS000000002FAK
...
AS000995481FAK
```

Comment: +1 but I hesitated - don't use single quotes for aliases! Also why no length definition on varchar? :-)

Comment: is there a way for it to be random, or does it have to increment?

Comment: There's no easy way to randomize.  You could do something simliar with a `NEWID()` I guess.

Comment: @Zee Tee you have been asked several times : WHY does it need to be random? Is it worth a much more expensive computation cost to make it so, and a cost that increases as "numbers" get used? What are you trying to achieve by making it random?

Comment: NEWID() is GUID right?, but will SQL know to make it unique in case the conversion ends up being a dupe?

Comment: @ZeeTee `GUIDs` are always unique.  They are **globally** unique, as in every sql server generates a new one that no other server anywhere else generates.  Collisions are possible but exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: Hi Aaron, It's because i don't want it to be an increment to expose the count.

Comment: @JNK, but after you convert it, it has the chance not to be unique anymore, will it?

Comment: @ZeeTee it'll be a 32 character string, so no it won't be non-unique

Comment: @JNK I don't want a `123123-123123-123123-123123-123123` as an invoice number, lol, thats way too long...

Comment: @ZeeTee If you want unique then you have to go with count or a long value.  A GUID is long to be statistically unique.   You could take a piece of a GUID then compare it to the current values and only use it if it is not already present.

Comment: @ZeeTee "i don't want it to be an increment to expose the count" - you can start the identity column from whatever number you like  - 234892348 - and make a new row increment it by any other (constant) number you like

Comment: @ZeeTee Any static increment is going to expose the order and you can only have a static increment on identity (that I know of).

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen a randomly generated invoice number. Most of them are usually a combination of multiple identifying fields. For example, one segment might be the companyID, another might be the InvoieID, and a third might be a Date value

For example, `AS-0001-00005-K` or `AS-001-00005-021712-K`, which would stand for CompanyId 1, Invoice #5, generated on 2/17/12

You said in a comment that you don't want to let the company know a count of how many past invoices there are, and this way they won't know the count except for how many invoices they have received, which is a value they should know anyways.

If you're concerned about giving away how many companies there are, use an alpha company code instead, so your end result looks like `AS-R07S-00005-K` or `ASR07S00005K`

Answer (score 2):

So you can do it this way, just don't expect it to perform well.

(1) populate a big massive table with some exhaustive set of invoice values - which should be at least double the number of invoices you *think* you'll ever need. Populate the data in random order in advance.

(2) create a stored procedure that pulls the next invoice off the pile, and then either deletes it or marks it as taken.

But, be sure that this solution makes sense for your business. In many countries it is actually law for invoice numbers to be sequential. I'm guessing we're not really talking about invoices, but wanted to make sure it's at least considered.

Comment: That seems really messy, i suppose using pieces of the GUID could work but the unique part is confusing.

Comment: If you populate the table in advance, you can delete the duplicates. You only ever populate the table once - your objection seems similar to the people who don't want a numbers table because they think it is inefficient to have one more table in their schema.

Comment: It's also a maintenance issue, i don't see that being truly scale-able.

Comment: Ok, I was working on a code sample to show you how easy it is, but since you've already decided it's not worth your time, I'm going to go to lunch instead. If you already know which solutions are good and which are bad, why are you asking the question? Let me know when you've discovered a more scalable solution that satisfies all of your requirements. Let me know when you discover a way to generate unique, non-sequential strings that doesn't get more expensive as the number of existing values you have to check against increases.

Comment: What if it can get more expensive?

Comment: Your inserts will get slower over time if you have to check the "random" number you just generated to make sure it doesn't already exist - because as you use up more invoice numbers, there are more to check.

Comment: i guess i was seeing if SQL had something like this built-in, and i guess it doesn't, i need to think about what i want to do.. thanks again for now..

Answer (score 0):

What is so confusing about the random part being unique?  If you have a two digit invoice number there can only be 100 unique values (00 - 99).  A GUID has 2 to the power 128 values and is statistically unique.   If you use a 8 characters of a GUID then with even 1 million invoices you have a betting chance of getting a collision.  With 1 million invoices if you use 12 characters of GUID then you have very good chance of NOT getting a collision.  If you use 16 characters of a GUID then you are pretty much statistically unique if you have less than 1 billion invoices. I would use 12 characters but check against actual values for uniqueness and you only have lottery chance of getting collision.

Answer (score 0):

How are you inserting these new invoices to the table? A straight up batch insert or are you doing some business logic/integrity checks in a stored procedure first and 'creating' the invoices one by one?

In the second case, you could easily build a unique ID in the procedure. You could store a seed number in a table and take the number from there then cast it as a varchar and append the alphanumeric characters, you can then increment the seed. This also gives you the option of creating a gap between unique IDs if you needed to import some records into the gap at a later date.